# How to inject x86 DLL from the WOW64 process to the x64 process

Tags: c++, windows, dll, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

Is there any way to inject x86 DLL from the WOW64 process to the x64 process? I know that according to MSDN it is not normally possible:

> On 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dynamic-link
>   library (DLL). Additionally, a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL

but I've found the following [code](https://github.com/OpenWireSec/metasploit/blob/master/external/source/meterpreter/source/common/arch/win/i386/base_inject.c) in the Metasploit's repository and wondered how to use it in my project:

```
/*
 * Attempt to gain code execution in a native x64 process from a wow64 process by transitioning out of the wow64 (x86)
 * enviroment into a native x64 enviroment and accessing the native win64 API's.
 * Note: On Windows 2003 the injection will work but in the target x64 process issues occur with new 
 *       threads (kernel32!CreateThread will return ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY). Because of this we filter out
 *       Windows 2003 from this method of injection, however the APC injection method will work on 2003.
 */
DWORD inject_via_remotethread_wow64( HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpStartAddress, LPVOID lpParameter, HANDLE * pThread )
{
    DWORD dwResult           = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    EXECUTEX64 pExecuteX64   = NULL;
    X64FUNCTION pX64function = NULL;
    WOW64CONTEXT * ctx       = NULL;
    OSVERSIONINFO os         = {0};

    do
    {
        os.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof( OSVERSIONINFO );

        if( !GetVersionEx( &os ) )
            BREAK_ON_ERROR( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: GetVersionEx failed" )

        // filter out Windows 2003
        if ( os.dwMajorVersion == 5 && os.dwMinorVersion == 2 )
        {
            SetLastError( ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED );
            BREAK_ON_ERROR( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: Windows 2003 not supported." )
        }

        // alloc a RWX buffer in this process for the EXECUTEX64 function
        pExecuteX64 = (EXECUTEX64)VirtualAlloc( NULL, sizeof(migrate_executex64), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );
        if( !pExecuteX64 )
            BREAK_ON_ERROR( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: VirtualAlloc pExecuteX64 failed" )

        // alloc a RWX buffer in this process for the X64FUNCTION function (and its context)
        pX64function = (X64FUNCTION)VirtualAlloc( NULL, sizeof(migrate_wownativex)+sizeof(WOW64CONTEXT), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );
        if( !pX64function )
            BREAK_ON_ERROR( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: VirtualAlloc pX64function failed" )

        // copy over the wow64->x64 stub
        memcpy( pExecuteX64, &migrate_executex64, sizeof(migrate_executex64) );

        // copy over the native x64 function
        memcpy( pX64function, &migrate_wownativex, sizeof(migrate_wownativex) );

        // set the context
        ctx = (WOW64CONTEXT *)( (BYTE *)pX64function + sizeof(migrate_wownativex) );

        ctx->h.hProcess       = hProcess;
        ctx->s.lpStartAddress = lpStartAddress;
        ctx->p.lpParameter    = lpParameter;
        ctx->t.hThread        = NULL;

        dprintf( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: pExecuteX64=0x%08X, pX64function=0x%08X, ctx=0x%08X", pExecuteX64, pX64function, ctx );

        // Transition this wow64 process into native x64 and call pX64function( ctx )
        // The native function will use the native Win64 API's to create a remote thread in the target process.
        if( !pExecuteX64( pX64function, (DWORD)ctx ) )
        {
            SetLastError( ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED );
            BREAK_ON_ERROR( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: pExecuteX64( pX64function, ctx ) failed" )
        }

        if( !ctx->t.hThread )
        {
            SetLastError( ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE );
            BREAK_ON_ERROR( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: ctx->t.hThread is NULL" )
        }

        // Success! grab the new thread handle from of the context
        *pThread = ctx->t.hThread;

        dprintf( "[INJECT] inject_via_remotethread_wow64: Success, hThread=0x%08X", ctx->t.hThread );

    } while( 0 );

    if( pExecuteX64 )
        VirtualFree( pExecuteX64, 0, MEM_DECOMMIT );

    if( pX64function )
        VirtualFree( pX64function, 0, MEM_DECOMMIT );

    return dwResult;
}
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>

#include <Windows.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct _WOW64CONTEXT
{
  union
  {
    HANDLE hProcess;
    BYTE bPadding2[8];
  } h;
  union
  {
    LPVOID lpStartAddress;
    BYTE bPadding1[8];
  } s;
  union
  {
    LPVOID lpParameter;
    BYTE bPadding2[8];
  } p;
  union
  {
    HANDLE hThread;
    BYTE bPadding2[8];
  } t;
} WOW64CONTEXT, *LPWOW64CONTEXT;

typedef BOOL(WINAPI * X64FUNCTION)(DWORD dwParameter);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI * EXECUTEX64)(X64FUNCTION pFunction, DWORD dwParameter);

BYTE migrate_executex64[] = "\x55\x89\xE5\x56\x57\x8B\x75\x08\x8B\x4D\x0C\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                            "\x58\x83\xC0\x25\x83\xEC\x08\x89\xE2\xC7\x42\x04\x33\x00\x00\x00"
                            "\x89\x02\xE8\x09\x00\x00\x00\x83\xC4\x14\x5F\x5E\x5D\xC2\x08\x00"
                            "\x8B\x3C\x24\xFF\x2A\x48\x31\xC0\x57\xFF\xD6\x5F\x50\xC7\x44\x24"
                            "\x04\x23\x00\x00\x00\x89\x3C\x24\xFF\x2C\x24";

BYTE migrate_wownativex[] = "\xFC\x48\x89\xCE\x48\x89\xE7\x48\x83\xE4\xF0\xE8\xC8\x00\x00\x00"
                            "\x41\x51\x41\x50\x52\x51\x56\x48\x31\xD2\x65\x48\x8B\x52\x60\x48"
                            "\x8B\x52\x18\x48\x8B\x52\x20\x48\x8B\x72\x50\x48\x0F\xB7\x4A\x4A"
                            "\x4D\x31\xC9\x48\x31\xC0\xAC\x3C\x61\x7C\x02\x2C\x20\x41\xC1\xC9"
                            "\x0D\x41\x01\xC1\xE2\xED\x52\x41\x51\x48\x8B\x52\x20\x8B\x42\x3C"
                            "\x48\x01\xD0\x66\x81\x78\x18\x0B\x02\x75\x72\x8B\x80\x88\x00\x00"
                            "\x00\x48\x85\xC0\x74\x67\x48\x01\xD0\x50\x8B\x48\x18\x44\x8B\x40"
                            "\x20\x49\x01\xD0\xE3\x56\x48\xFF\xC9\x41\x8B\x34\x88\x48\x01\xD6"
                            "\x4D\x31\xC9\x48\x31\xC0\xAC\x41\xC1\xC9\x0D\x41\x01\xC1\x38\xE0"
                            "\x75\xF1\x4C\x03\x4C\x24\x08\x45\x39\xD1\x75\xD8\x58\x44\x8B\x40"
                            "\x24\x49\x01\xD0\x66\x41\x8B\x0C\x48\x44\x8B\x40\x1C\x49\x01\xD0"
                            "\x41\x8B\x04\x88\x48\x01\xD0\x41\x58\x41\x58\x5E\x59\x5A\x41\x58"
                            "\x41\x59\x41\x5A\x48\x83\xEC\x20\x41\x52\xFF\xE0\x58\x41\x59\x5A"
                            "\x48\x8B\x12\xE9\x4F\xFF\xFF\xFF\x5D\x4D\x31\xC9\x41\x51\x48\x8D"
                            "\x46\x18\x50\xFF\x76\x10\xFF\x76\x08\x41\x51\x41\x51\x49\xB8\x01"
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x31\xD2\x48\x8B\x0E\x41\xBA\xC8"
                            "\x38\xA4\x40\xFF\xD5\x48\x85\xC0\x74\x0C\x48\xB8\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00\xEB\x0A\x48\xB8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                            "\x48\x83\xC4\x50\x48\x89\xFC\xC3";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [pid]" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  int pid = std::atoi(argv[1]);
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Invalid pid" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  HANDLE process_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
  if (process_handle == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function OpenProcess. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(process_handle)
  {
    CloseHandle(process_handle);
  };

  LPVOID load_library_addr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
  if (load_library_addr == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function GetProcAddress. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  const char* dll_path = "D:\\helper.dll";

  LPVOID dll_path_memory = VirtualAllocEx(process_handle, NULL, strlen(dll_path) + 1, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if (dll_path_memory == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function VirtualAllocEx. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  BOOL res = WriteProcessMemory(process_handle, dll_path_memory, dll_path, strlen(dll_path) + 1, NULL);
  if (res == 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function WriteProcessMemory. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  HANDLE thread_handle = CreateRemoteThread(process_handle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)load_library_addr, dll_path_memory, 0, NULL);
  if (thread_handle == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function CreateRemoteThread. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    EXECUTEX64 pExecuteX64 = (EXECUTEX64)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(migrate_executex64), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (pExecuteX64 == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function VirtualAlloc. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    X64FUNCTION pX64function = (X64FUNCTION)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(migrate_wownativex) + sizeof(WOW64CONTEXT), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (pX64function == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function VirtualAlloc. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::memcpy(pExecuteX64, &migrate_executex64, sizeof(migrate_executex64));
    std::memcpy(pX64function, &migrate_wownativex, sizeof(migrate_wownativex));

    WOW64CONTEXT* ctx = (WOW64CONTEXT *)((BYTE *)pX64function + sizeof(migrate_wownativex));
    ctx->h.hProcess = process_handle;
    ctx->s.lpStartAddress = load_library_addr;
    ctx->p.lpParameter = dll_path_memory;
    ctx->t.hThread = NULL;

    if (!pExecuteX64(pX64function, (DWORD)ctx))
    {
      std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!ctx->t.hThread)
    {
      std::cerr << "ctx->t.hThread is NULL" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HANDLE hThread = ctx->t.hThread;

    if (ResumeThread(hThread) == (DWORD)-1)
    {
      std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function ResumeThread. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  WaitForSingleObject(thread_handle, INFINITE);

  std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

It works perfectly in case of injecting x86 DLL to the x86 process but not in the case of injecting x86 DLL to the x64 process (the injected process just crashes).

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though it doesn't do exactly the same thing (inject x86 code into an x64 process), have you considered using a COM wrapper?  I have used COM to solve this issue going in both directions (x86 to x64, or x64 to x86).  Don't try to load the dll in process though, use the windows surrogate server.

Comment: @Steven Hansen Can you give me more info about it? Also I don't have source code of the both applications -- I'm trying to fix bug in one software

Comment: In your COM wrapper, you create your own custom interface and load/call into the Dll as normal.  Source code for the Dll is not required.  Just research COM servers.  Sometimes these are written with ATL (might be helpful term for your search), and Visual Studio supports quite a few helpers for writing them.

Comment: According to the comments in the Metasploit code you've posted, it does *not* inject 32-bit code into the target 64-bit process.  It injects 64-bit code into the target 64-bit process, *from* a 32-bit process.

Answer (score 2):

**Not really**.

A 64 bit Windows OS can natively run 64 bit code and also use WOW64 to run 32 bit code. However, every process may only be one or another.

When going into the internals, you can see that each process is either labeled as 32 bit or 64 bit. When the OS will instruct the CPU to run a thread associated with that process, it will either jump as 32 bit or 64 bit code.

Therefore if you somehow load 32 bit bytecode (doesn't matter where does it code from, either a DLL or something else) into a 64 bit process, when the OS will run it, the process will crash because the process will be in 64 bit mode, and will interpret the opcodes as 64 bit opcodes.

Same goes for running 64 bit code on 32 bit code.

**Edit**:

In fact, it is possible for a x32 WOW64 process to execute x64 code.According to this [article](http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=102). However, I couldn't find resources about a x64 process to running x86 code.

Comment: They uses more WinAPI functions than I posted -- look at the source code in the Metasploit's repository. In fact, they does the same -- injecting DLL to the x64 process from the WOW64 process, so I wondered what's wrong in my case

Comment: Did you check whether Metasploit's code successfully injects a x86 DLL into a x64 process?

Comment: Actually there are claims that you can, in fact, switch between 32bit and 64bit within a process. I'm checking this out - http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=102

Comment: Check this out: http://spth.virii.lu/v1/articles/HEAVEN.TXT - it is possible for a process to use the appropriate assembly to switch modes (how come the OS doesn't foribid it?). However, there is no OS API for this and is generally unsupported.